# Degraded RAID 5 array, can't add replacement drive

Tags: ubuntu, raid, ubuntu-14.04, raid-5

So I've had two drives that have been marked as faulty spares in my RAID, I've removed them then I tried to --force assemble the RAID but this came up -

```
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 2 drives and 1 spare - not enough to start the array.
```

I then tried to add the new drive to the pool, ended up with this -

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdc1
mdadm: cannot get array info for /dev/md0
```

I then tried to check the status of the raid -

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
mdadm: md device /dev/md0 does not appear to be active.
```

What would be the best way to add the new drive to the RAID?

Comment: How many active drives was the RAID 5 array supposed to have? And are you  trying to save the data or just build a new array?

Comment: **Two** lost drives in RAID 5 -> Wipe the old RAID, create a new one. Restore the data from your backups.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz There were 4 drives originally, I'm not sure at the moment, I think my best option is to try to access the data, backup then build a new array. I assume trying attempting to rebuild without a backup would be risky?

Comment: @superandy07 You're way past the point of making a backup now.